# Duplicate Primary Key while populating new table from old table

Tags: mysql

I've created multiple indexed tables that I want to tie into a new normalized version of an old table. I get everything indexed and the relations set and I get a "Duplicate entry '11' for key 'Primary' " error message.

Here's the code I'm using to populate the new table.

```
insert into dvdNormal(dvdId, dvdTitle, year, publicRating, dvdStudioId, 
dvdStatusId, dvdGenreId)
(
select dvdId, dvdTitle, year, publicRating, studioId, statusId, genreId
from dvd d
join dvdStudio on d.studio = dvdStudio.studioName
join dvdStatus on d.status = dvdStatus.dvdStatus
join dvdGenre on d.genre = dvdGenre.genre);
```

Comment: Thank you for the status report!  Did you have a **question** you wanted to ask? Or were you just sharing information about your current development efforts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you were asking a **question**, and not just giving a **status report**.

The behavior you observe is (most likely) due to the insert statement attempting to insert a row that violates a UNIQUE (or PRIMARY KEY) constraint defined on the `dvdId` column in the target table (the table the statment is inserting rows into.)

And either 1) the `dvdId` column is not unique in the table it's being retrieved from, or 2) there is more than one "matching" row in one of the other three tables.

For example, if `dvdId` is a column in `dvd`, and it's defined as UNIQUE, then case 1) doesn't apply.

But if that row from `dvd` has *more than one* "matching" row from one (or more)  of the other three tables, then we'd expect the SELECT to generate "duplicate" values for `dvdId`.

For example, if the `genre` column is not unique in `dvdGenre` table, or `studioName` column is not unique in `dvdStudio`, we'd expect the query to return multiple copies of the row from `dvd`. The redundant data (duplicated values) is expected when we "denormalize" data.

If we want to get the table loaded from the query, there's a couple of options.

If we want to store every row returned by the query, we would remove the UNIQUE constraint from the `dvdId` column. (There may also be other UNIQUE constraints that need to be removed from the target table.)

If we only want to store one copy of the row from `dvd`, along with values from one matching row from each of the other tables, we could leave the `UNIQUE` constraint, and use an `INSERT IGNORE` statement to avoid throwing a "duplicate key error". Any rows where that error would have been thrown will be discarded, and won't be inserted into the target table.

Because the column references aren't qualified, we can't actually tell which table the `dvdId` column is beint returned from. We can't tell which table *any*  of the columns are returned from. We can "guess" that `genreId` is being returned from the `dvdGenre` table, but for us to figure that out, we'd need to investigate the schema definition. It's not a problem for MySQL, it can lookup the table definitions a whole lot faster than we can.

We could aid to the future reader of that SQL statement by *qualifying* the column references with the tablename, or a table alias.